# Why is this:Interface<T> not of type Interface<T> using an IS keyword comparison?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to figure out why using the `is` keyword seems to differ when I cast. Here's a test case showing what I am looking at:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestMy {

    public interface IBaseMessage { }

    public interface IMessageProcessor<T> where T : IBaseMessage {
        void Process(T msg);
    }

    public class RRMessage : IBaseMessage {
    }

    public class BaseMessageProcessor {
        public bool CanProcess<T>(T msg) where T : IBaseMessage {
            return this is IMessageProcessor<T>;
        }
    }

    public class RRMessageProcessor : BaseMessageProcessor, IMessageProcessor<RRMessage> {
        public void Process(RRMessage msg) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1() {
        var msgProcessor = new RRMessageProcessor();
        var msg = new RRMessage(); 
        Console.WriteLine(msgProcessor.CanProcess(msg));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2() {
        var msgProcessor = new RRMessageProcessor();
        var msg = new RRMessage() as IBaseMessage; 
        Console.WriteLine(msgProcessor.CanProcess(msg));
    }
```

Why does Test1() return `True` and Test2() return `False`. How can I implement `CanProcess()` so that it returns `True` in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type inference in `Test1` means it's calling

```
msgProcessor.CanProcess<RRMessage>()
```

... whereas in `Test2` it's calling

```
msgProcessor.CanProcess<IBaseMessage>()
```

Now `RRMessageProcessor` doesn't implement `IMessageProcessor<IBaseMessage>` - you can't call `Process(justAnyMessage)` - it *only* knows how to process `RRMessage` values. So it's really entirely reasonable, basically.

To make both tests return true, you don't really want a generic method, because you only care about the *execution-time* type of `msg`. There are a few options here:

- Have a private generic method, but call it with an argument of type `dynamic`, in which case the type inference will be performed using the execution-time type of the message:

  ```
  public bool CanProcess(IBaseMessage message)
  {
      dynamic d = message;
      // Perform type inference at execution time
      return CanProcess(d);
  }

  private bool CanProcess<T>(T message)
  {
      return this is IMessageProcessor<T>;
  }
  ```
- Check the interfaces using reflection, e.g. calling `typeof(IMessageProcessor<>).MakeGenericType(msg.GetType()).IsAssignableFrom(GetType())`

Note that you still need to be slightly careful - suppose you had some `SpecialRRMessage` deriving from `RRMessage`... then an `RRMessageProcessor` could still reasonably process it, but it doesn't implement `IMessageProcessor<SpecialRRMessage>`.

You may want to change your `IMessageProcessor<T>` interface so that `T` is declared to be *contravariant*:

```
public interface IMessageProcessor<in T> where T : IBaseMessage
```

At that point, your `RRMessageProcessor` *would* implement `IMessageProcessor<RRMessage>` due to contravariance.

Comment: thank you. How can I fix it so that it returns true in both cases? I would assume that .NET does know that msg is RRMessage under the hood and this processor should be able to handle it.

Comment: @Denis; See my expanded answer.

Comment: Jon, So I was playing around with changing it to IMessageProcessor<in T> but that didn't change anything, it still returns false for Test2(). Would it be possible for you to post code on how you would re-write it so that it works?

Comment: @Denis: I've already given two options... The contravariance bit is in addition to that, to handle the other situation I talked about, where you want a base class processor to handle a derived type message.

Comment: Jon, thank you for the clarification for #2 - that's a pretty cool approach to construct the type from the class and its generic type. I was interested in what you meant by #1 (private generic method). Was looking for an example there...

Comment: @Denis: I've added an example. I'd use the second option though.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. Never knew that trick with dynamic. Good to learn something new...